# Ruby On Rails Error Can't Convert Nil Into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I keep getting error can't convert nil into string following is my cod for the the controller and view and new to this any ideas or suggestions as to what could help fix it?

```
class ShowDateTimeController < ApplicationController
  def display
    @title = "Some Project For Date and Time"
    @current_time = Time.now.asctime
    @current_time2 = Time.now
    t = Time.now
    @h= t.hour
    @m= t.min
    @s= t.sec
    @v= Time.now.strftime ("%B")

    t.hour.to_s

    if t.hour > 6 && t.hour < 18
      @img = "sun.jpg"
      @name = "Good Morning The Sun Is Up"
    else
      @img = "moon.jpg"
      @name = "Good Night The Moon Is Up"


      if Time.now.month == 1
        @img_month= "jan.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==2
        @img_month = "feb.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==3
        @img_month = "mar.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==4
        @img_month = "apr.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==5
        @img_month = "may.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==6
        @img_month = "jun.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==7
        @img_month = "jul.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==8
        @img_month = "aug.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==9
        @img_month = "feb.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==10
        @img_month = "oct.jpg"
      elsif Time.now.month ==11
        @img_month = "nov.jpg"
      else
        @img_month = "dec.jpg"
```

The error when viewing in local host when I try to get the image from the vaiable `@img_month`

`image_tag @img_month, :class => 'img'`<---- the error is here yes i did use rails delimeter `<%=>` but still there is error

Comment: Could you fix the indentation and add the missing `end` statements?

Comment: Hey, just a suggestion: you could use something like Date::MONTHNAMES[Time.now.month][0..2].downcase + ".jpg" to generate a filename

Comment: @bassneck: There is also Date::ABBR_MONTHNAME. But for some reason september has feb.jpg, so this won't work.

Comment: thnx West you are correct fixing the indentation and adding a missing end to the first set of if then statements helped.  now the app works perfectly.  thanks everyone for the comments :)

Answer (score 2):

The `end` is probably missing after your first `if`:

```
    if t.hour > 6 && t.hour < 18
          @img = "sun.jpg"
          @name = "Good Morning The Sun Is Up"
    else
          @img = "moon.jpg"
          @name = "Good Night The Moon Is Up"
    end # <---- this one
```

So, `@img_month` is not set in the daytime.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't set `@img_month` variable if `t.hour > 6 && t.hour < 18` is true - it will be `nil` then.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is it always going through `t.hour > 6 && t.hour < 18` true condition, because if it is true, you are not setting a @img_month variable (As the variable sets only in else part).

Having the @img_month in top of your code, before conditions, with a default value would fix your issue.

Note: it's better if you could get these find of presentation logic to helpers. Just pass a value and write a helper to generate your images. And try something @bassneck suggested, as it's more DRY.